# unable to delete a network drive in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, network-shares

I have 3 mounted network drives mounted to the i:, y:, and z: drives on my Windows 7 machine.  I am able to unmount drives i: and z: just fine by either right clicking and choosing "Disconnect", or by executing `net use z: /delete` in the command prompt.  However, my y: drive will simply not disappear from explorer.  the drive it is mounted to no longer exists, so I have no use for it anymore, but when I execute `net use y: /delete`, the drive simply gets a red 'X' over it indicating that the netwotrk drive cannot be found, rather than removing itself from My Computer.

If anyone has experienced similar issues, please let me know how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Open the Start menu and enter `regedit` into the Search box and press enter. In the left side panel, locate the following key:

`[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2]`

Under this key there will be several entries. You will be looking for entries that look like: `##SERVER#FOLDER` (Where `##SERVER#FOLDER` = `\\Server\Folder`)

Delete the offending entries and reboot.

## Disclaimer:

**Be careful editing the registry in this way. Manually editing the registry can cause system cause system instability is done inproperly. I take no responsibility for damage done to your system as a result of this answer. You have been warned.**